# Is there a method to determine that a string is in the correct format?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a scenario that a user may enter a format string to format some parameters.
How can i determine that a format string is not valid based on specific count of parameters in .NET Framework (C#)?
Is there any method in framework to do that? or I must try a manual way?

sample situation:

```
string format = "test {0}, {1}";
var res = string.Format(format, 23);
```

Comment: How about "{0}, {0}"?  "{0:Z}"?  Etcetera.  It's a pretty unfriendly UI that only a .NET programmer could use.  At least show a preview of the formatted result so a problem is immediately evident.  If not from an exception then from the resulting string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Regex in order to validate format of string, below an article on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Parsing format strings is not always straightforward because of how escaped braces are counted (see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)), but a regular expression and `Regex.Matches().Count` should be accurate enough:

```
string format = "test {0}, {1}";
var expectedParameters = Regex.Matches(format, "(?<!\\{)\\{[^}]*?\\}").Count;
```